# How to break/escape from a for loop in Scala?

Tags: scala

Im new to scala and searched a lot for the solution. 
I'm querying the database and storing the value of the http request parsed as a json4s object in response. I wait for the response and parse the json.

```
val refService = url("http://url//)
val response = Http(refService OK dispatch.as.json4s.Json)
var checkVal :Boolean = true
val json = Await.result(response, 30 seconds)

val data = json \ "data"
```

I want to run a loop and check if the value of "name" is present in the data returned. If present I want to break and assign checkVal to false. So far I have this:

```
for {
  JObject(obj) <- data
 JField("nameValue", JString(t)) <- obj //nameValue is the column name in the returned data
  } yield {checkVal= if (t == name){ break }
 else 
   true
  }
```

Eclipse is giving me the following error: type mismatch; found : List[Unit] required: 
     List[String]
Please advice. Thank you.

Comment: In scala you should try to step back from these imperative notions ("run a loop") and express the higher-level intent. What about something like: `val checkVal = obj.find(jf => jf.fieldName == "nameValue").map(_.value ==t).getOrElse(true)` (I don't know the specific API, but hopefully you get the idea)?

Comment: Sorry if this these are dumb questions.. But here Im assuming checkVal is a boolean? And can you explain what `.map(_.value ==t)` does? Thank you.

Comment: It's a call to `.map` on an `Option` (the return type of `find`) - the easiest way to understand this stuff is to put it in an IDE and click through to the function definitions. `map` basically applies the given function to the value in the option if the option is present. `_.value==t` is an anonymous function, it's a concise way of writing e.g. `{jsonField => jsonField.value == t}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of your problems is that you have different return types in yield: if t==name, return type is the type of break, and if t!=name return type is Boolean.
In scala you don't have **break** operator, this behaviour is achieved using `breakable` construct and calling `break()` method which actually throws an exception to exit from `breakable` block. Also you can use `if` statements in `for` body to filter you results:

```
import scala.util.control.Breaks._

breakable {
  for {
    JObject(obj) <- data
    JField("nameValue", JString(t)) <- obj
    if t == name
  } yield {
    checkVal = false
    break()
  }
}
```

UPDATE: 
I used this imperative approach because you are new to scala, but it's not scala way. IMHO you should stick to @Imm code in comments to your question.

Answer (score 0):

I actually don't like using pattern matching in for loops as if for some reason data is not a JObject it won't be handled well. I prefer an approach like below.

```
data match {
  case JObject(fields) => fields.exists{
    case (name:String,value:JString) => name == "nameValue" && value.s == "name"
    case _ => false
  }
  case _ => false // handle error as not a JObject
}
```

Edit: revised to include your matches.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use `exists` as it is lazy on all collection members.

code:-

```
val list= Map(
        "nameValue1" -> 1,
        "nameValue2" -> 2,
        "nameValue3" -> 3,
        "nameValue4" -> 4,
        "nameValue5" -> 5
        )
val requiredHeader = "nameValue2"
var keyvalue:Int=0
list.exists(p=>{ if(p._1.equalsIgnoreCase(requiredHeader))keyvalue=p._2;p._1.equalsIgnoreCase(requiredHeader) })

if(keyvalue!=0){
        //header present
}else{
        //header doesn't exit
}
```